# glDrawArray not drawing the second time

Tags: c++, opengl

Hi so i have been basically pulling my hair out trying to understand this OpenGL confusion

i have tried to find answers in books, in tutorials , and even experimenting around with it

SO basically i have a opengl program that draws the first time my two triangles, however when i try to redraw the first triangle again it doesnt seem to be working

i dont know what information i am missing , but its no t making any sense

as far as i understand once the VAO and VBO have been created and bounded and buffered to memory, and vertex attrib pointers set and enabled that once i bind the vao object that i want to draw as many times as i like, i just have to do that

after initialization which works for me, the problem is that once i rebind another vao object it doesnt seem to draw it

my code is quiet long , i can paste it here if you like, but i think that the drawing part of the code would be sufficient

here it is

```
          GLfloat vec[] = {0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, -1.0f,
                           -1.0f, -1.0f};

          GLfloat vec2[] = {0.0f, 1.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                           -1.0f, 0.0f};

   //next step is to upload data to graphics memory

   //generating a buffer from openGL 
   GLuint vbo;
   GLuint vbo2 ; 

   GLuint vao;
   GLuint vao2;

   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2);

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);

   //to upload the actual data must make the object active by binding it to a target
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

   //upload the data of active object to memory
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec), vec, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);

   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec2), vec2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



   //bind and draw

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
   glBindVertexArray(vao);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);


   glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
   glXSwapBuffers ( dpy, glxWin );

   sleep(3);

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   //rendering second triangle 

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
   glBindVertexArray(vao2);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

   glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
   glXSwapBuffers ( dpy, glxWin );

   sleep(3);
   //rendering the first triangle again------where the problem lies!!!
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glBindVertexArray(vao);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);


   glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
   glXSwapBuffers ( dpy, glxWin );

   sleep(3);
```

Comment: and if you also clear the depth buffer? glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: that worked like a charm!!! why does the depth buffer bit need to be cleared in order for the first triangle to be redrawn? the tutorials dont mention that anywhere

Comment: answer the question below and i will mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also need to clear the depth buffer `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

If you follow a tutorial then you will probably have enabled depth testing in the openGL setup boilerplate it provided. This is because more people will want to use the depth buffer than not.

you can also not call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` during setup.